Counting and comparing values across dataframes to create new dataframe
Let's say I have 50 dataframes with an index of dates and a column labeled yes/no.
I would like to count the number of yes's/no's for a specific date across the dataframes to create a new dataframe that has the % of yes's and % of no's for each date.
Right now I'm planning on making separate lists of the dataframes and dates then using nested for loops to compare and count each date's datapoint across the yes/no columns. Not terribly manual, but also not sure if that's the best way of going about it.
Would love to hear anyone's thoughts on a more intuitive way of doing this or if my approach is flawed.

I would pd.concat all dataframe together then use a groupby count.

Is the date index unique? And how big are the dataframes?

Welcome. Please take the time to write a [mre]. Input sample, expected output, and your closest code attempt.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The following example dataframes have been setup to have identical datetime index, however i believe this should still work fine even if the dates across the dataframes  are not identical.
test1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'check': ['yes', 'no', 'yes','yes','no','no','yes','no','yes','no','yes']
})
test1.index = pd.date_range(start='2024-01-01', periods=len(test1), freq='D')

test2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'check': ['yes', 'yes', 'yes','yes','no','no','yes','yes','yes','no','yes']
})
test2.index = pd.date_range(start='2024-01-01', periods=len(test2), freq='D')

test3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'check': ['no', 'yes', 'no','yes','no','yes','no','no','yes','no','yes']
})
test3.index = pd.date_range(start='2024-01-01', periods=len(test1), freq='D')

The first step is to concatenate the dataframes into a single dataframe. We set axis=1 to join the columns together.
combined_df = pd.concat([test1, test2, test3],axis=1)

combined_df
As already mentioned, there is no need to worry about the column names being the same. However, if you do want to change the column names for another purpose you can simply use the following, though again, it is not required for this task.
number_of_frames = 3
combined_df.columns = [f'frame_{i}' for i in range(1,number_of_frames+1)]

We can then use pandas apply method to go through each row and count the unique values. We also need to fill any missing values with zero using the fillna method.
results = combined_df.apply(lambda row: row.value_counts(normalize=True), axis=1)
results = results.fillna(0)

After all of this we get:
results
You can also reduce the number of decimal placings:
results = results.round(4)

Also, if you want the actual tally and not the %, you can simply remove normalize=True and it will give the you the number of yes's and no's.

Welcome. See [answer] for tips. Code-only answers are not recommended.

Good general approach avoiding loops. Notes: it is not necessary to rename the columns; code will work fine without this line and thennumber_of_frames is not required either; it is necessary to use .fillna(0) on the results DF to replace NaN values. As already commented, some explanation would be useful for subsequent viewers and also to show the results from the test data..

Wow thanks for the detail Michael, will use this as my baseline for solving my issue today
